# How to synchronize coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to make sure these two methods are synchronized. What I noticed is that Coroutines are harder to synchronize than Threads. How can I guarantee that if I call `start()` then `stop()` that my code will actually be stopped at the end?

```
object Test {

    private val coroutine = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

    @Synchronized
    fun start() {
        coroutine.launch {
            // some work
        }
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun stop() {
        coroutine.launch {
            // clean up then stop
        }
    }
}
```

My concern is I call `start()` then `stop()` but actually stop executes first. So my code continues when it should have stopped.

Comment: Do you want semantics akin to `ExecutorService.submit(task)`? Enqueue some units of work and have them executed asynchronously, but in the order of submission? If yes, then you should use an `actor`.

Answer (score 20):

Synchronization or sequential execution of commands are two different things.
If you need execute "start" then "stop", simply do not create new coroutines with your's "coroutine.launch", instead use suspend keyword for your function, then execute them like this :

```
suspend fun start() {}

suspend fun stop() {}

fun main() {
    scope.launch {
        start()
        stop()
    }
}
```

But if you want to synchonized two method you can read [an official Kotlin guide to shared mutable state](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html) which presents a few good solutions. And do somethink like this :

```
val mutex = Mutex()

suspend fun main() {
    mutex.withLock {
        start()
        stop()
    }
}
```

Comment: your second example doesn't work because `Mutex.withLock` is a `suspend` fun and requires to run inside a `suspend` function too

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **cancel the started** Job when `stop()` is called, save the job in a field:

```
object Test {

    private val coroutine = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
    private var startedJob : Job? = null

    fun start() {
        startedJob = coroutine.launch {
            // some work
        }
    }

    fun stop() {
        runBlocking { startedJob?.cancelAndJoin() }
        coroutine.launch {
            // clean up then stop
        }
    }
}
```

--

If your problem is the **calling sequence** - first start, then stop - then you have to check and synchronize the code which calls your `Test` object.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Deferred` Job with a boolean, then use `await()` on it to wait for completion. Something like this:

```
fun doSomeWork() {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        val isStartingComplete = start().await()
        // await() will wait for the completion of the start() function
        if (isStartingComplete) {
            stop()
        }
    }
}

fun start(): Deferred<Boolean> {
    return GlobalScope.async (Dispatchers.IO) {
        // Do your start work
        true
    }
}

fun stop() {
    // Do your stop work
}
```

Comment: Just for your information: `Deferred` is **not a function, it's interface**. https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/

Comment: @JeelVankhede Yes, you are right, I'll update `function` to `Job` as it is more in line. However, the code should work fine for the given question.

Answer (score -3):

You just need a `Job` in the `CoroutineScope`:

```
object Test {

    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + Job())

    fun start() {
        scope.launch {
            // some work
        }
    }

    fun stop() {
        scope.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Job()`?

Comment: @J_Strauton The `Job` defines the lifecycle of whatever to execute in you coroutine. If you launch new coroutines (or rather suspending functions) their "Jobs" will become children of your job, so that if you cancel your coroutine they would also be cancelled (clean themselves up)

Comment: What interface does `Job()` implement?

Comment: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/ or rather this because the `Job()`-function I used actually returns a `CompleteableJob `https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-completable-job/index.html

Comment: there is no different between `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + Job())` and `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)` "If the given [context] does not contain a [Job] element, then a default `Job()` is created."

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon Didn't realize that. But still `scope.cancel()` cleans everything up for you.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, it's about the ordering of launched tasks. OP's second task is "stop", which is why he asks "will my code actually be stopped at the end". His worry is that the "stop" task will get reordered and run before the "start" task.

Comment: Ahh ok. Then I'd recommend using an `Actor` instead.